# Is swarm required for using multi-host networking feature using overlay in docker

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-swarm

I have followed through the example at [getting started overlay](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) and i have a simple query. Is it possible to use multi-host networking feature using overlay without creating a `swarm cluster`? I don't want to use third party plugins like weave etc. I want to use docker native networking support for this.

I have `3.16+ kernel` running RHEL and `docker 1.9`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible: see "[Lab 6: Docker Networking](https://github.com/code-monkeys/dceu_tutorials/blob/master/6-networking.md)".
The key part of an overlay network is the discovery service, like for instance [**Consul**](https://www.consul.io/).

> An overlay network requires a key-value store.
> The store maintains information about the network state which includes discovery, networks, endpoints, ip-addresses, and more. Engine supports Consul, etcd, and ZooKeeper (Distributed store) key-value store stores.

[image: https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/raw/master/images/tut6-step1.png]

The article "[Docker Networks: Discovering Services on an Overlay](https://medium.com/on-docker/docker-networks-discovering-services-on-an-overlay-66c8906ffd49#.uoml91xv5)" lay some criticisms about the current service discovery tools which are not built for individual container registration or discovery.

> Overlay uses KV stores under the covers to model the network topology and enable cross-host container to container communication. It does not provide [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) resolution.
>
> The rub is that in an overlay network every container has its own IP address.
> So, the only way you could make this work is by running Consul agents inside of every container on the network that contributes a service. That is certainly not transparent to the developer, or compatible with off-the-shelf images.

Comment: Thanks @VonC . I somehow wasn't aware of this documentation availability at github. :-)

Comment: One more doubt @VonC, Can we not launch the `KV` store image (zookeeper etc. ) on one of the nodes where clustered containers are to be run?

Comment: @AnkitKumar yes you can. Don't forget to restart docker with the right options (https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/94fd5f3e9372a8f58ca7b25f3232305731f7cd36/06-networking.md#task-2-configure-the-engine-to-use-key-value-store). that node needs to be reachable by the others. It is better to keep it separate on its own node though.

Comment: Out of curiosity @AnkitKumar why have you opted for multi host networking without the swarm ?