# How to run docker containers on different machines

Tags: architecture, docker, devops, docker-machine

I've setup several docker containers for my application:

1. container for mysql
2. container for application server (tomcat7)
3. container for nginx
4. container for python tornado application

On my local machine, using `docker-machine`, I've tried all these containers and them interactive with each other. I created one virtualbox machine with boot2linux and setup all these containers on it.

Now, for production I am going to run each one of these containers on a separate server. Is there something docker provides to quickly/easily do this? Or should I set up docker on each server, copy relevant images to that server, and then start docker-images manually on all servers?

Answer (score 2):

> Or should I set up docker on each server, copy relevant images to that server, and then start docker-images manually on all servers?

Yes, but you should also:

- create the [relevant libnetworks](https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/docker-networking-takes-a-step-in-the-right-direction-2/) in order for your containers to be registered in them
- create as first container a [KV one (Key-Value: Consul, etcd, Zookeeper, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34894042/6309) that will monitor each containers in each network(/machine), allowing them to see each others.
  Note: you might want to use a docker 1.10 for adding a [network-scoped alias to your containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34921289/6309).

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/images/overlay_network.png]

Then you can create your containers on your machines.

See a practical example at [Understand Docker container networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/)

Comment: I would suggest using a registry for you containers. Building them on each host is fine, but there's not really any need when you can centralise.

Comment: @Sobrique I agree. Interestingly enough, I am currently, for my assignment, building my own registry. Note: beware of the change in addressing the image with docker 1.10 (https://blog.docker.com/2016/01/docker-1-10-rc/)